# How can I implement iterate in linear hierarchy?

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have this class ( interface):

```
public interface IParentChiled
{
    IParentChiled Parent { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

and there is method that should **returns child's name prefixed with all its parents' names separated by the specified separator**. something like : parent/child. the method is like this:

```
 public string GetFullName(IParentChiled child, string separator = null)
 {
        separator ??= "/";
        throw new NotImplementedException();
 }
```

**My Questions are  :**

**1**. What is the name of this type of Class/Interface that use itself as property?

**2**. How can I impalement the Method?

Comment: I can't seem to find an official definition for this type of thing. I just call them recursive properties. For the method you can also have a sort of recursion. I would make it an abstract class instead of an interface in this case. That way you can have a method in the abstract class called `GetName` (or similar) that returns it's name plus the result of calling `GetName` on it's parent. If it's parent is null, just return an empty string. Alternatively you could make an extension method that does this rather than making it an abstract class.

Comment: This is similar to a singly linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a string like

```
Root/Parent/Child
```

you can

1. Enumerate items (you can easily do it in `Child, Parent, Root` order).
2. `Reverse` the enumeration.
3. `Join` the items into the final string.

Possible implementation:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// static: we don't want "this" in the method
public static string GetFullName(IParentChiled child, string separator = null) {
  // Enumerate Names but in reversed order      
  static IEnumerable<string> Items(IParentChiled last) {
    for (IParentChiled item = last; item != null; item = item.Parent)
      yield return item.Name;
  }

  return String.Join(separator ?? "/", Items(child).Reverse());
}
```

You can implement this as an *extension method* for the `IParentChiled` interface:

```
using System.Linq;

...

public static class ParentChiledExtensions {
  public static string GetFullName(this IParentChiled child, string separator = null) {
    // Enumerate Names but in reversed order      
    static IEnumerable<string> Items(IParentChiled last) {
      for (IParentChiled item = last; item != null; item = item.Parent)
        yield return item.Name;
    }

    return String.Join(separator ?? "/", Items(child).Reverse());
  }
}
```

Now you can use `GetFullName` method as if it's implemented by interface:

```
IParentChiled item = ...

Console.Write(item.GetFullName("."));
```

Comment: love that `for` loop!

Answer (score 0):

there may be better solutions but i'd do something like this:

```
public string GetFullName(IParentChiled child, string separator = null){
    separator ??= "/";
    var parent = child;
    string name = child.name;
    while(parent.parent!=null){
        parent = parent.parent;
        name = parent.name + separator + name;
    }
    return name;
}
```